# Why is decoding time more for animated webP?

Tags: image, image-processing, gif, animated-gif, webp

I am experimenting with animated webP to compare compression with GIF. I have observed that loading animated webP on internet has some delay as compared to gif for same animation. So there must have been time in decoding webP on browser(chrome in this case).

Going through documentation on google developers I came across:

"***In the absence of seeking, straight-line decoding of WebP is more CPU-intensive than GIF. Lossy WebP takes 2.2x as much decode time as GIF, while lossless WebP takes 1.5x as much.***"

First of all what is seeking? 
And secondly, is it possible to introduce seeking in webP while transcoding from gif to reduce decode time?

Answer (score 1):

Seeking is when you decode frame 0 and then seek ahead to frame 2 instead of "straight line" decoding of frame 1. Seeking has to move around in the file while decoding frame 1 after frame 0 is faster since the file is already at the location where data for frame 1 is located.